# Proving Equivalence Relation in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

I just need to see if this is correct

Define a relation R on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ by $<a,b>$ R $<c,d> $ iff $a+d=c+b$. Prove this is an equivalence relation.

I am having an issue with the reflexive case. I wrote let $<a,b>\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Then $a+b=b+a$ by commutativity, thus $<a,b>$ R $<a,b>$, but should I instead be using $<a,a>$.

Then for symmetric, I have that $<a,b>,<c,d>\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that $<a,b>$ R $<c,d>$, $a+d=c+b$. Then,$a+d=b+c$= $d+a=b+c$, which we can just rewrite as $d+a=c+b$. Then, this shows $<c,d>$ R $<a,b>$

For transitivity, I have let $<a,b>,<c,d>,<x,y>\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that $<a,b>$ R $<c,d>$ and $<c,d>$ R $<x,y>$. So, we have that $a+d=b+c$ and $c+y=d+x$. Then, we can do $(a+d)+(c+y)=(b+c)+(d+x)$. We can cancel out the $c$ and $d$ from both sides by subtracting and are left with $a+y=b+x$. Then, $<a,b>$ R $<x,y>$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly shown that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

To answer your question regarding reflexivity: No, you should not use $\langle a,a \rangle$. A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is reflexive if, for any $x\in X$, we have $x R x$. In your case, $X=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, so you need to show that $x R x$ for an arbitrary element $x\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. This element should be of the form $\langle a,b\rangle$, not $\langle a,a\rangle$. (Which is just as you did :))

Comment: Thank you, then everything is correct?

Comment: @Sam There is a typo at the end of your symmetric case "$d+a=c+d$" that I just noticed.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I mixed up the letters at the beginning. I tried to fix them, but then does this make sense for reflexive?

Comment: @Sam Yes it does

Comment: Then, for reflexive it would just be trivial because we would have a+b=a+b?

Comment: It is actually a+d=c+b not a+d=b+c. Then, would this also change the rest?

Comment: @Sam Yes it follows from commutativity. For the same reason, the conditions $a+d=c+b$ and $a+d=b+c$ are equivalent and hence won't change anything. (Although it may be nicer to reflect the change in the way you write the proof).

Comment: Yes, I see. I am just a bit confused as to how this would change my proof for symmetry if we use the a+b=c+b instead because for reflexive the effect was we no longer need to consider commutativity because just having a+b=a+b gives us the relationship as defined.

Comment: @Sam Try writing it out with this changed relation as you did in your question. I'm sure you'll be able to notice the differences.

Comment: Okay, I will update the answer. I think I caught the change. Instead of saying a+d=b+c equals d+a=c+b by commutativity, it would just be that a+d=c+b equals c+b=a+d. This is just rewriting the same thing, it is not commutativity correct?

Comment: @Sam Correct. It's just symmetry of "$=$".

Comment: Okay, just one question about cancellation in this case, since we are working in the natural numbers, it is okay to do this subtraction of c and d? I will also be updating an answer soon, I just want to make sure I write it out correctly first.

Comment: @Sam In the natural numbers, we have cancellation with respect to addition. That is;
$$
a + b = a + c \iff b=c.
$$

Comment: Then my use of saying "we can cancel out c and d on either side of the equation" is fine?

Comment: @Sam Yep, that's right!

Comment: Okay thanks! I got it now, just had to do symmetry and commutativity in different ways, but still got equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. Concerning reflexivity, what you should (and did) prove was that$$(a,b)\operatorname{R}(c,d)\iff(c,d)\operatorname{R}(a,b).$$

Answer (score 1):

For another approach, note that $(a,b) R (c,d) $  iff $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$, where $f: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is given by $f(x,y)=x-y$.
Since equality is an equivalence relation, so is $R$.